# Message from popup to content script not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have a chrome extension, the use case of the chrome extension goes like this:

Part-1

1. The chrome extension has a popup page  that contains 2 div elements and a button
2. As soon as I click the popup, gets the current tab's URL sends it to background script using chrome.runtime.sendMessage API
3. The background script has an message listener does an xhr request using cookies, fetches the data related to the url and then sends it back to popup.js
4. The popup.js edits the 2 div elements based on the data it receives

This part works perfectly, however the second part becomes a bit tricky:

Part-2:

1. If we click the button in the popup, using some data obtained in part-1 a bit of time conversion has to be done
2. After this time conversion I need to interact with DOM of the page and edit few elements for this I need to send the result of the time conversion to the content script
3. To achieve Point-2, as a part of test I am using chrome.tabs.sendMessage API to send the data specifically to the tab's content script and expecting it to get it back, but I get the below error, in popup.js

**Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.**

Please find my manifest, background, timezone and popup.js(my content script) code below:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name" : "Switcher",
    "version": "1.1",
    "browser_action":{
        "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },
    "permissions":["tabs","activeTab","cookies","<all_urls>"],
    "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"],
            "persistent": false
        }
    
}
```

**Popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
   var obj = {"active": true, "currentWindow": true}
    chrome.tabs.query(obj, function(tab){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({url: tab[0].url, action: "id_load"},function(response) //Send message to background script with the URL of the tab
        {
              //Manipulate the popup divs using the response from background script

         })

    })

    var timezone = document.getElementById("change_timezone")
    timezone.addEventListener('click',change_timezone_function)
    function change_timezone_function()
    { 
        var query_info = {active: true, currentWindow: true}
        chrome.tabs.query(query_info, function(tab){
            console.log(tab[0].id)
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id,{time: ticket_time},function(response) //Send message to the content script by getting the tab ID
           {
                console.log(response)
            })
        })
         
    }    
})
```

**background.js**

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
         function(request,sender,sendResponse)
        {
         //Do some manipulation, few api calls and send response asynchronously after the api call is successful
          return true
     })
```

**timezone.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse){
    var date_time = new Date(request.time.toString())
    console.log(request.time)
    sendResponse({date_time: request.time})
})
```

***All of the answers point to the fact that popup.js can interact with the content script using tab specific messages but this does not seem to work, I think this might be because of the Listener in Background, but logically there is no basis to believe so, since my message from popup is specifically sent to the content script of the tab.***

Comment: To send a message to a content script you need to declare it in manifest.json or inject with chrome.tabs.executeScript, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still have few queries,one is I am doing a programmatic injection, so I'll try the one given in the docs, aside from that the docs say content scripts support onmessage Apis, so why isn't my message being sent? Also since I am doing programmatic injection I believe activeTab permission should be enough, isn't it? I have also tried declaring the content script and URL patterns as given in docs still i face the same issue.

Comment: 1) I don't understand the confusion. To receive a message there should be something to receive it. Currently you do not have a content script to receive it. Hence the message cannot be sent. 2) See [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) documentation for more info. 3) When you edit manifest.json you need to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page and reload the tabs. It's also possible your declaration is incorrect so I can't help without [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: @wOxxOm Adding an example folder
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1R9FdEXjkmQX8c4RwgfqOP-1AQ6xwtA-8?usp=sharing
This is using a simple onmessage listener in content script. I have declared it in Manifest yet facing the same error. I will try out the programmatic injection separately and let you know.
Does declaring content script execute them as soon as the page loads? or do they wait for an action like a button click from popup?

Comment: It runs after DOMContentLoaded so you probably need to specify [document_start](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time).